# Regex, devise & brakeman. Ruby on rails 5.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, devise, brakeman

I'm using the given regex expression to validate the username:

```
validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, :multiline => true
```

By running `brakeman` gem i'm having the following warning.

```
== Warnings ==

Confidence: High
Category: Format Validation
Check: ValidationRegex
Message: Insufficient validation for `username` using `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/`. Use `\A` and `\z` as anchors
File: app/models/user.rb
Line: 16
```

What would be the optimal regex expression to correctly assign those anchors and keeping the same character permissions?

Regex is yet a myth for me!
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ruby on rails guides regular expressions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions)

To fix the regular expression, \A and \z should be used instead of ^ and $, like

`/\A[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*\z/`